# Dynamic generate buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to dynamic generate a few buttons, the number will be given by background. When I get it, I must use it to create the corresponding number buttons，each button will be the same size and the space between them are the same, if the button can not contain in a row, it will line feed. The minimum width will be a constant，but the actual length will be according title text of the button. 
My code is below, but it can't line feed, also I don't know how to use the text to determine the length of the button, grateful for any guidance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat testHeight = 50;
    CGFloat testWidth = 100;
    CGFloat spaceing = 10;
    int number = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {   
        UIButton *button =  [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(spaceing + testWidth * i + spaceing * i , 100 , testWidth, testHeight )];  
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];  
        [self.view addSubview:button];
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are looking for is a "Grid of buttons" search for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `UICollectionView` to do this, but it is not difficult to implement just using an array of `UIButtons`. You can use `sizeToFit` to have the button size itself based on its title. To get your buttons to wrap you should just check if it will extend past the max x of the view you are adding them to, in your case `self.view`.

For example you could say something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *buttonStrings = @[@"how", @"now", @"brown", @"cow", @"the", @"quick", @"brown", @"fox"];
    NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[buttonStrings count]];
    for (NSString *string in buttonStrings)
    {
        UIButton *button = [self buttonForString:string];
        [buttons addObject:button];
    }
    [self layoutButtonArray:buttons inView: self.view];
}
// takes an array of buttons and adds them as subviews of view
- (void)layoutButtonArray:(NSArray<UIButton *> *)buttons inView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGFloat spacing = 10.0;
    CGFloat xOffset = spacing;
    CGFloat yOffset = spacing;
    for (UIButton *button in buttons)
    {
        if((xOffset + button.bounds.size.width + spacing) > CGRectGetMaxX(view.bounds))
        {
            xOffset = spacing;
            yOffset += (button.bounds.size.height + spacing);
        }
        button.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, button.bounds.size.width, button.bounds.size.height);
        [view addSubview:button];
        xOffset += (button.bounds.size.width + spacing);
    }
}
// Takes a string returns a button sized to fit
- (UIButton *) buttonForString:(NSString *)string
{
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [button setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];
    // if you want to have a minimum width you can add that here
    button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, MAX(button.frame.size.width, kMinWidth), button.frame.size.height);
    return button;
}
```